# How to stick a list of block tensors to form a larger tensor in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, torch

Assume that there is a list of small tensors (say 16 blocks), and it is desired to stick these small tensors along horizontally and vertically to create a larger 2D image.

torch.split() is available for partition the tensor to smaller blocks, is there any operation for the opposite case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `torch.cat` with `dim`. To stack tensors vertically use `torch.cat(..., dim=0)`, to stack horizontally use `torch.cat(..., dim=1)`:

*Example*:

```
tensors = torch.split(torch.randn(4, 6), 2, dim=1)

tensors
(tensor([[-1.0257,  0.5213],
         [-0.1181, -1.4420],
         [-1.5563, -1.0757],
         [ 1.1788,  0.6222]]), tensor([[-0.4531, -0.1260],
         [-0.2383, -1.3542],
         [-0.8752, -0.4728],
         [ 0.7879,  1.3686]]), tensor([[ 2.3357, -0.6220],
         [ 0.2687,  0.1146],
         [ 0.9912, -0.0586],
         [-0.8507,  0.5126]]))
```

Stack vertically along first dimension:

```
torch.cat(tensors, dim=0)
tensor([[-1.0257,  0.5213],
        [-0.1181, -1.4420],
        [-1.5563, -1.0757],
        [ 1.1788,  0.6222],
        [-0.4531, -0.1260],
        [-0.2383, -1.3542],
        [-0.8752, -0.4728],
        [ 0.7879,  1.3686],
        [ 2.3357, -0.6220],
        [ 0.2687,  0.1146],
        [ 0.9912, -0.0586],
        [-0.8507,  0.5126]])
```

Stack horizontally along second dimension:

```
torch.cat(tensors, dim=1)
tensor([[-1.0257,  0.5213, -0.4531, -0.1260,  2.3357, -0.6220],
        [-0.1181, -1.4420, -0.2383, -1.3542,  0.2687,  0.1146],
        [-1.5563, -1.0757, -0.8752, -0.4728,  0.9912, -0.0586],
        [ 1.1788,  0.6222,  0.7879,  1.3686, -0.8507,  0.5126]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm already aware of the torch.cat, but the problem is that for sticking a set of blocks in a 2D way, doing vertical and horizontal orders does not help.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example to showcase your input and attempted code?

Answer (score 0):

Building block matrices can be done with a bit of fiddling with matrix operations. Lets say you have 4 matrices *A*, *B*, *C* and *D* you want to stack into

> *A* *B*
>
> *C* *D*

```
a = torch.tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
tensor([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
b = torch.tensor([[5,6],[7,8]])
tensor([[5, 6],
        [7, 8]])
c = torch.tensor([[-1,-2],[-3,-4]])
tensor([[-1, -2],
        [-3, -4]])
d = torch.tensor([[-5,-6],[-7,-8]])
tensor([[-5, -6],
        [-7, -8]])
```

Then concatenate, transpose and break into two chunks. (Transpose is needed because we will transpose later, and this one cancels out).

```
x,y = torch.cat((a,b,c,d),dim=1).t().chunk(2)
(tensor([[1, 3],
         [2, 4],
         [5, 7],
         [6, 8]]), 
 tensor([[-1, -3],
         [-2, -4],
         [-5, -7],
         [-6, -8]]))
```

Next put those two matrices side-by-side and transpose

```
torch.cat((x,y),dim=1).t()
tensor([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
        [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
        [-1, -2, -5, -6],
        [-3, -4, -7, -8]])
```

It should be straightforward to generalise to *N*x*N* block matrices.